# Need to obtain the field value in OpenERP7.0 form, but got an object

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

I'm building a Bar-code manager and need to get the field value from the form. My test looks like like:

```
res = self._columns['rsid']
_logger.error("the result is : %d",% (res))
raise osv.except_osv(_("Test"), _(res._type))
```

But in the log in found it says: "the result is : openerp.osv.field.char object ox898943".

In the window it says char.

The type of the field rsid I defined is char.

Why is it doing this?

Answer (score 0):

the field in the form was declared as an openobject field, that's why you see it as an osv.field. Anyway, it is a char as well, and you can read it and manipulate it as a char object

Comment: I know what you probably want to say,but I still don't know how to get  the field value

Answer (score 0):

To view the info message in an osv exception do this:

```
message='type: %s' % res._type
_logger.error("the result is : %d",% (res))
raise osv.except_osv(_("Test"), _(message))
```